# Running NUnit tests in ASP.NET 5 project (within VS Test Explorer)

Tags: nunit, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I am developing an ASP.NET 5 application targeting dnx451.

Unlike in a "normal" class library project, the test classes are not discovered by the VS2015 Test Explorer after build.

I tried both with NUnit Test Adapter VS Extension (2.0.0.0) installed as well as by adding NUnitTestAdapter NuGet package to the test project.

Am I missing something or is this a general issue with the DNX execution model?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the equivalent command for nunit in your project.json file?

```
 "commands": {
     "test": "xunit.runner.dnx"
 },
```

and have you rebuilt your solution?

Answer (score 0):

We're using **[NUnitLite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnitLite/)** to run **[NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/)** tests in our **ASP.NET Core** applications.
My main issue was actually finding the documentation for this package, which is available at **https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/NUnitLite-Runner**.

1. Create a console application project.
2. The minimal `Main` method to run the tests could look like this:

   ```
   using NUnitLite;

   public class Program
   {
       public int Main(string[] args)
       {
           return new AutoRun().Execute(args);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create a command to start the project (i.e. the console application). In the example `project.json` file shown below the command `Test` will run all tests except those annotated with `[Category("SlowTest")]`.

   ```
   {
       "version": "1.0.0-*",
       "description": "Tests for the SelfServicePortal",

       "dependencies": {
           "SelfServicePortal": "1.0.0-*",
           "NSubstitute": "1.9.2",
           "NUnit.Runners": "3.0.1",
           "NUnitLite": "3.0.1",
           "NUnit.Console": "3.0.1",
           "Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
       },

       "commands": {
           "Test": "SelfServicePortal.Tests -where \"cat != SlowTest\""
       },

       "frameworks": {
           "dnx451": { }
       }
   }
   ```

Hope this helps. Here's a test run with some unnecessary censoring:

[image: Sample test run with unnecessary censoring]